# Access specific value in javascript multidimensional object

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am trying to access a specific value in a multidimensional object but I can not get the value, it keeps giving output as undefined or [Object, Object]. How can I get the value **src** from object below:

I tried **file['path'].src** and **file.path.src** but still undefined.

I am using Ionic and MediaObject, and also gives me error in editor "path is not defined object in MediaObject"

```
path: {"_objectInstance":{"id":"c4bede41-d413-bdc1-2158-d99d9e1876a9","src":"/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/71EF3AA9-8B2C-48F4-92A4-C9DE16CF8346/tmp/audiofile.wav","_duration":-1,"_position":-1},"onSuccess":{"_isScalar":false},
```

Comment: `file.path._objectInstance.src` try this . `_objectInstance` missing

Comment: @prasanth If I use the above it says property path does not exist

Comment: can you post full correct object? in your question object is doesn't valid . please post as working fiddle